# How to use WHMCS Local api (internal API)

Tags: api, whmcs

How to use WHMCS LocalAPI (InternaAPI)

Hi
I have a problem to use WHMCS LocalAPI
WHMCS Documentation is very poor and unclear about this problem
when I run this code a blank page appear and any thing is happened

```
<?php
require('../init.php');
require('../includes/api.php');
$command = 'AddOrder';
$postData = array(
    'clientid' => '1',
    'domain' => array('domain1.com'),
    'billingcycle' => array('annually'),
    'domaintype' => array('register',),
    'regperiod' => array(1),
    'nameserver1' => 'ns1.demo.com',
    'nameserver2' => 'ns2.demo.com',
    'paymentmethod' => 'zarinpalgw',
);
$adminUsername = 'myadminname'; // Optional for WHMCS 7.2 and later

$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername);
print_r($results);


?>
```

I expected to add order after run this code
External API is very slow and not suitable for me for some reason such as 
I have a dynamic IP and External API work with static IP because IP must be recognize in WHMCS->General setting->Security

Answer (score 1):

The [Internal API](https://developers.whmcs.com/api/internal-api/) code in your example looks like it should work. Temporarily enabling PHP errors can help narrow down the exact cause of this issue ([Setup > General Settings > Other > Display Errors](https://docs.whmcs.com/Enabling_Error_Reporting)), although I believe it is due to the way you are initializing the WHMCS environment in your PHP file.

WHMCS provides specific guidelines on building custom pages, which appears to be what you were trying to do in the example provided. Custom PHP files must be located in the root WHMCS directory, however `require('../init.php');` indicates that your script is currently inside a subdirectory. You also should not be requiring api.php, as that is already being handled by init.php. **Moving your script to the WHMCS root directory and commenting out the `require('../includes/api.php');` line should hopefully fix the blank page issue.**

**Please note:** the example you provided does not display the normal WHMCS client interface and does not check to see if the user is logged in. If that is functionality you will be needing as well, you can create a page with the same interface and functionality as a native WHMCS client area page. The following is a slightly modified version of the example code WHMCS provides in their guide for [creating client area pages](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/):

```php
<?php

// Define WHMCS namespaces
use WHMCS\ClientArea;
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

// Initialize WHMCS client area
define('CLIENTAREA', true);
require __DIR__ . '/init.php';
$ca = new ClientArea();
$ca->setPageTitle('Your Page Title Goes Here');
$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php', Lang::trans('globalsystemname'));
$ca->addToBreadCrumb('mypage.php', 'Your Custom Page Name');
$ca->initPage();

// Uncomment to require a login to access this page
//$ca->requireLogin();

// Uncomment to assign variables to the template system
//$ca->assign('variablename', $value);

// Code to run when the current user IS logged in
if ($ca->isLoggedIn()) {
    $clientName = Capsule::table('tblclients')->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->pluck('firstname');
    $ca->assign('clientname', $clientName);

// Code to run when the current user is NOT logged in
} else {
    $ca->assign('clientname', 'Random User');
}

// Setup the primary and secondary sidebars
Menu::addContext();
Menu::primarySidebar('announcementList');
Menu::secondarySidebar('announcementList');

// Define the template filename to be used (without the .tpl extension)
$ca->setTemplate('mypage');

// Display the contents of the page (generated by the Smarty template)
$ca->output();
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.my problem is solved with your information.

Comment: Understood, glad I could be of assistance. If you feel that my answer sufficiently addressed your issue, could you please mark it as accepted? If not, no worries... I just wanted to be sure you understood the process. More info on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers